# Programatically create a background gradient in Swift

Tags: swift

So usually to create a gradient I might have the following `UIViewController`:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 238/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = true
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

However, I want the equivalent when I'm programatically creating the ViewController.

I've tried the following:

```swift
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view = view
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let bgView = UIView()
        bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 238/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = true
        bgView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        self.view.addSubview(bgView)
}
```

But all I see in the red background colour.

How can I add a background gradient programatically?

Comment: Update ```gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds``` this inside the ```viewDidLayoutSubviews()``` method.

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: No. i thought is frame issue so I suggest you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bgView` has `.zero` frame, so anything inside it is not visible.

```
let bgView = UIView()

// Add this line
bgView.frame = view.bounds

bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

#### UPDATE

Seems like the `view.bounds` has zero width/height and that's causing `bgView` to not be visible on screen.

You can try waiting for subviews to be laid out properly before adding this gradient.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
        // This view has zero frame here
        let view = UIView()
        
        // Do you see red color on your screen at all?
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // If you don't see red color on your screen at all
        // then you need to fix the frame for your view
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        self.view = view
    }

    private lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 238/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradient.shouldRasterize = true
        return gradient
    }()

    private lazy var bgView: UIView = {
        let bg = UIView()
        bg.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        return bg
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.addSubview(bgView)
        bgView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        bgView.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.frame = bgView.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try printing `bgView.frame` & `gradientLayer.frame` and verify that these have non zero values for width & height?

Comment: They are zero. But that line does not fix it - unfortunately.

Comment: See the **UPDATE** in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
func gradientBackground() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 94.0/255.0, blue: 58.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
                
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.gradientBackground()
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

The view's bounds are zero in viewDidLoad so the gradientLayer has a zero frame.  Setting the gradientLayer's frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews will fix the issue (will need to make gradientLayer an instance variable so that you can reference it in viewDidLayoutSubviews):

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view = view
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bgView = UIView()
    bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 238/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    bgView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    self.view.addSubview(bgView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
}
```